# Проблема с сертификатами

Tags: java, jar, сертификат, цифровая-подпись, javaws

У меня есть java web start приложение. Используется несколько jar-файлов. Раньше jar-файлы были подписаны сертификатом "А". Теперь у меня новый сертификат "Б", я подписал им свои jar. И теперь при запуске javaws-приложения с сервера оно пытается проапдейтить мои jar до нужной версии (`jnlp.versionEnabled=true`), но выдается ошибка, что мои jar из локального кэша и с сервера подписаны разными сертификатами.

> JAR resources in JNLP file are not
>   signed by same certificate

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Может он решил обновить одни jar'ы, а другие нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очистить java кэш на стороне клиента